# FTP does not work after being 5 minutes inactive

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I have an application that makes simulations.In the beginning of each simulation, FTP connection is created and after that some  upload/download files operations are done.
then simulation starts.After simulation finishes, again some upload file operations is required for back up simulation related folders

We encounter a problem if simulation takes more than 5 minutes.In the mean time, FTP connection is idle.I get following exceptions.

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:276)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:236)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:477)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:537)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:586)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:794)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:788)


Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:295)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:495)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:537)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.mkd(FTP.java:1363)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.makeDirectory(FTPClient.java:1971)
```

I tried following actions just after simulation is completed, I tried to reinitialize FTP , but no success.I see that connection is active in FTP side

1)FTPClient.isConnected() method returns true

2)When I call FTPClient.connect(), it throws exception FTP is already initialized

3)I tried to set timeouts in connect method of FTP.

```
public boolean connect() throws IllegalStateException, FileTransferException {
    /*
     * Precondition checks
     */
    final FTPClient clientBefore = this.getClient();
    if (clientBefore != null && clientBefore.isConnected()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("FTP Client is already initialized");
    }
    // Create the client
    final FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(600000);
    client.setDefaultTimeout(600000);
    // FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_NT);
    // client.configure(conf);
    log.trace("Connecting to FTP Server at " + config.getCanonicalForm());
    try {
        client.connect(config.getHost(), config.getPort());
        client.setSoTimeout(600000);
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        throw new FileTransferException("Error in connecting to " + config.getCanonicalForm(),
                ioe);
    }
    log.trace("Connected to FTP Server at: " + config.getCanonicalForm());
    this.setClient(client);
    // Check that the last operation succeeded
    this.checkLastOperation();
    boolean result;
    try {
        // Login
        if (client.login(config.getUserName(), config.getPassword())) {
            result = true;
            // If there's a pwd defined, cd into it.
            final String pwd = this.getPresentWorkingDirectory();
            if (pwd != null) {
                this.cd(pwd);
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new FileTransferException("Could not log in", e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, I am on deadlock.I do not know what is the problem

Comment: ftp servers commonly only tolerate relatively short idle times, if you actually need your connection to sit there doing nothing you should regularly send some dummy command to avoid closing by the server.  Or, if this is just for test/sim purposes, try to increase the server's timeout, if you have control over the server.

Comment: Since FTPClient.isConnected() method returns true, maybe set your program to disconnect after the uploads etc are done and then reconnect when you need to transfer more files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have to keep the connection alive, run NOOP commands against the server, so that the control connection remains alive.

Either do it manually:

```
client.sendNoOp();
```

Or set the client to do it at fixed interval rates:

```
client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300); // set timeout to 5 minutes
```

But if you can avoid wasting resources, [logout](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#logout()) and [disconect](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#disconnect()) after the initial download phase, do your local processing and [connect](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect(java.lang.String)) / [login](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#login(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) again for uploading afterwards.

Comment: why following calls does not make anything? Why are not they keeping connection alive? client.setConnectTimeout(600000);
   client.setDefaultTimeout(600000);

Comment: Your code is telling the ftp client: 1) to wait for the server about 10 minutes before before reporting that a connection timeout happened 2) to wait 10 minutes before reporting that a socket couldn't be open (kinda nonsense, if the server didn't answer within milliseconds chances are that you will not be able to establish the connection). These are client timeouts, you have no control over server timeouts. 
To circumvent the problem, the code mentioned above sends `NOOP` commands to the server so that it keeps the control connection alive.

Comment: I use commons net 2.2 in the project.It does not have setControlKeepAliveTimeout(int sec) method implementation.It has setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive).I tried this.But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Remember in addition to ftp timeout mentioned by others that any firewalls / NAT in the communication path may time out, in typically less than 5 minutes.

Comment: My firewall is OFF.How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Dive into the source code.

When FTPClient make the control connection connect

```
client.connect(config.getHost(), config.getPort());
```

it use some code works like this:

```
Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
```

to create a socket to connect to the ftp server.

If you can, set keepalive option to socket, using

```
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

Hierarchy:

```
├── SocketClient
│   ├── FTP
│   │   └── FTPClient
```